# How to call const_iterator for non const class?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, constants

I read some other threads related to this issue but non offered a solution for my problem. I hope you guys can give me ideas or advices.

I'm trying to implement this class named `Map`. it should contain 2 iterators - `iterator` and `const_iterator`.

I have them implemented - `iterator` inherits from `const_iterator`, and in the `Map` class I have the following functions:

```
iterator begin();
iterator end();
const_iterator begin() const;
const_iterator end() const;
```

we were given an example file to see what is required to implement. 
in there, there is the following code:

```
Map<std::string,int> msi;
```

...

```
// print map
for(Map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it = msi.begin(); it != msi.end(); ++it) {
// more stuff here
}
```

since `msi` is a non-const Map instance, `msi.begin()` calls to `iterator begin()` and not `const_iterator begin() const`, resulting in unintended behaviour.

Assuming the example file is okay, how do I make it so `msi.begin()` calls the correct `const_iterator` function? (considering it, the iterator, is of type `const_iterator`).

EDIT: regarding the talk about the auto-conversion, i decided to add my iterator classes, please point out my mistake.

```
class Map {

    //...

    public:

        class const_iterator {

        private:

            Node* currNode;

        public:


            const_iterator(Node* cur_node = NULL) : currNode(cur_node) {}

            const_iterator& operator++() {
                currNode = currNode->next;
                return *this;
            }

            const_iterator operator++(int) {
                const_iterator old = *this;
                ++(*this);
                return old;
            }

            bool operator!=(const_iterator const& curr) {

                return !(*this == curr);
            }

            string operator*() {
                // this might cause memory leak
                string toString(this->currNode->key);
                std::stringstream s;
                int tmp = this->currNode->value;
                s << tmp;
                string secondString(s.str());
                toString = toString + ":" + secondString;
                return toString;
            }

            bool operator==(const_iterator const& curr) {
                return this->currNode == curr.currNode;
            }


            void operator=(const_iterator target) {
                this = target;
            }

            //void operator=(Node* target) {
            //    this->currNode = target;
            //}
        };

        class iterator : public const_iterator {

        private:

            Node* currNode;

        public:

            iterator(Node* cur_node = NULL) : currNode(cur_node) {}

            iterator& operator++() {
                currNode = currNode->next;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator++(int) {
                iterator old = *this;
                ++(*this);
                return old;
            }

            bool operator==(iterator const& curr) {
                return *this == curr;
            }

            bool operator!=(iterator const& curr) {

                return !(*this == curr);
            }

            string operator*() {
                // this might cause memory leak
                string toString(this->currNode->key);
                std::stringstream s;
                int tmp = this->currNode->value;
                s << tmp;
                string secondString(s.str());
                toString = toString + ":" + secondString;
                return toString;
            }

            void operator=(iterator target) {
                this = target;
            }

        };

        //..
}
```

Comment: Why is calling the `iterator` version bad exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 standard containers add `cbegin` and `cend` for that purpose. Lacking that, you can obviously always cast your object to `const&` explicitly to get a `const` view on the object.

More fundamentally, however, there’s no reason why your `iterator` shouldn’t support an automatic conversion to `const_iterator`. Like that, you’d not need to change the client code at all. In fact, your code should already support this if, as you’ve said, `iterator` inherits from `const_iterator`.

However, the code you’ve posted contains several errors. Firstly, `operator=` is wrong, and you should have received an error for it. The corrected version is:

```
void operator=(const_iterator target) {
    currNode = target.currNode;
}
```

More importantly, your inheritance makes no sense. True, you *do* inherit `iterator` from `const_iterator` but your code pretends that this never happened – `iterator` completely reimplements its parent class and doesn’t relate to it in any way.

`iterator` should rather look something like this:

```
class iterator : public const_iterator {
public:
    iterator(Node* cur_node = NULL) : const_iterator(cur_node) {}
};
```

This requires of course that `currNode` is declared `protected` in `const_iterator`. That class is also completely useless (but so is yours, at the moment) since it doesn’t add any functionality to the `const_iterator` class. You need to implement an `operator*` which allows modifying its value. Your current code fundamentally doesn’t allow this since it returns a newly created string rather than (something akin to) a reference to a map value.

Furthermore, it’s unclear how the `const_iterator` class gets ahold of a non-`const` `Node` pointer in the first place. That shouldn’t be possible: after all, it gets the pointer from a `const Map`.

Comment: `template<class T> T const& as_const(T& v){ return v; } // wheee`

Comment: Could you expand on how to implement the auto-conversion? I think if the OP knew how to do it, they would have.

Comment: @deworde According to OP, the conversion *is* already implemented (“`iterator` inherits from `const_iterator`”).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but in that case shouldn't this be working automatically, rather than "resulting in unintended behaviour"?

Comment: this is exactly why i ask - but i get no auto-conversion. i can add my iterator classes, maybe something went wrong

Comment: @KonradRudolph added my iterator classes, please inspect them for my mistake

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks alot! will dive into this and hopefully ill get no more difficulties

Answer (score 0):

If you will define msi

```
const Map<std::string,int> msi;
```

instead of

```
Map<std::string,int> msi;
```

const version of begin() and end() will be invoked